# How to set the font-size relative to the grand father instead of the parent?

Tags: css

I have a `span` with `font-size:0` to suppress spaces:

```
<span style="font-size:0">
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
</span>
```

The inner spans inherit the font size of the parent and disappear, too. Using `font-size:100%` does not help either, because it is also relative to the parent.

How can I define the font size relative to the grand father?

Comment: With pure CSS you can't; why do you have it set to font-size: 0?

Comment: @ExplosionPills see line 1

Comment: _“I have a span with font-size:0 to suppress spaces”_ – I don’t think that’s a good way to do it anyway – since many browsers have a minimum font-size in their settings that can not be undercut (and I don’t know if they are willing to abandon that rule for elements containing just whitespace or not).

Comment: Suppress whitespace another way: using an HTML comment from closing tag to the next opening one or writing the closing tag right in front of the next opening one...

Comment: @FelipeAls I can also write everything in one line. Possible but not readable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to change font size relative to an ancestor that is higher than another defined font size in pure CSS, i.e. you can't.  There are several possible workarounds, though:

- Use JavaScript to calculate the correct font size
- Instead of `font-size: 0` on the outer span, use `float: left` on the inner span
- Change the HTML to remove the space
- Just use a set font size for the inner spans

Comment: `float:left` on the inner seems to be an alternative for `font-size:0`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rem` ('root' ems) units to set the `span`'s `font-size` relative to the base font-size:

```
<span class="hideSpaces">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
</span>


body { font-size: 16px; } /* <-- base font-size */
.hideSpaces { font-size: 0; }
.hideSpaces span { font-size: 1rem; } /* <-- sets font size equal to base font size */
```

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: Compatibility is IE9+ as stated in the article you're referencing (and no Opera Mini according to caniuse)

Comment: @FelipeAls If that's a concern, OP can specify specific font-sizes for older browsers: `.hideSpaces span { font-size: 16px; font-size: 1rem; }`

Comment: `rem` is root em, not grandparent em.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Gee thanks I didn't realize that. Sill me offering a potential solution to the OP's issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I recommend actually reading an answer before downvoting and commenting on it.

Comment: The question asked was “How can I define the font size relative to the grand father?”, and the answer does not address that question. If you offer a solution to something that you regard as the real problem, as opposite to the question asked, you should state the assumed real problem explicitly.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You must be joking.

Comment: base font-size is no go 1. px in base font-size is no go 2.

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to use a very small percentage instead of zero for the font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/DzXZv/

```
span {font-size: 0.1%; }
span > span {font-size: 100000%;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give font-size in pixel.

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/uqHgW/`
```

Comment: `px` for font size is a no go.